# Include generated Jar and aar as a dependency in Android project

Tags: android, gradle, jar, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I have a AndroidStudioSupport Project which has modules. 
1. module 1 takes care of Android UI part
2. module 2 is a library project which generates .aar file
3. module 3 is a java project which generates jar file

Now I want to build the project in a way that
1. First build jar project 
2. Then copy generated jar into libs of library project as a dependency
3. Then build aar file 
4. Then copy generated aar into libs of UI project as a dependency
5. Finally generate .apk file

Please suggest me what changes do I have to do in my gradle files

jar project gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    test.java.srcDirs = ['tests/java']
    test.resources.srcDirs = ['tests/resources']
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}
    }
}
```

library project gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':java_project')
}

task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

build.dependsOn(copyToLib)

android {
    publishNonDefault true
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('test')
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
        }
    }
}
```

This current implementation doesn't include jar from my java project

Comment: Well we can't see your gradle files, so we can't advise what changes need to be made.

Comment: You want a multi-project build, what's wrong with the normal way `include 'subproject'` `compile ':subproject'` stuff?

Comment: @weston I have added my gradle files

Comment: So you have an imperative set of requirements in the question; I want to do this, then that, then the other. Gradle is better used declaratively; these are the tasks, theses are their dependencies on each other, do this. That is what you already have, what is the problem with what you have?

Comment: @weston Current implementation doesn't include any classes from jar project. So I decided to add generated .jar as a dependency